# I have specified the size of the array using user input but my for loop is taking input only size-1 time

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have specified the size of the array using user input but my for loop is taking input only size-1 time.

```
 import java.util.*;
        public class Main{
            public static void main(String args[]){
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                int time=sc.nextInt();
                String input[]=new String[time];
                for(int i=0;i<time;i++) 
                {
                input[i]=sc.nextLine();
                }
                for(int i=0;i<time;i++) 
                {   
                int len=input[i].length();
                if(len>4)
                {
                    System.out.println(input[i].charAt(0)+ Integer.toString(len-2)+input[i].charAt(len-1));
                }
                else
                    System.out.println(input[i]);
            }
        }
        }
```

i changed my code and it is working fine
changed

```
int time=sc.nextInt();
```

with

```
int time=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

but i don't know the reason behind this . Please can anyone explain me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Scanner.nextInt()` method scans the next **token** of the input as an `int`, not the line. For example, if you give an `int` input and then hit enter, then it takes only the `int`, not the carriage return.

If you give a sample input like this:

```
2 xyz //hit enter and give the next input
abc
```

You'll see the `nextInt()` will take the `2` as input from that line and the upcoming first iteration for `Scanner.nextLine()` will consider the `xyz` as first input and in the next iteration, as we gave `abc`, it will be considered as the second. All these time you're code was working, but you couldn't see as it was taking the empty string as the first input due to the carriage return from the previous line.

However, The `Scanner.nextLine()` takes the whole line as input, along with the carriage return and then parses the int to the integer, so, you get the next lines for the string input for your array.

Hope that makes everything clear.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your explanation gave me a idea of what is happening here but still i can't understand why the element at index 0 is empty?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, `scanner.nextLine()` takes the carriage return which was ignored by the `scanner.nextInt()`. Hence, empty.

Comment: is there any other better approach to implement this thing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `nextLine()` method used in the first `for` loop. Because the method advances the scanner to the next line and returns the input that was skipped, it kind of "eats" one of your loop iterations and it ends up allowing you to input `time - 1` elements into the array instead of `time` amount of elements. If you just use `sc.next()` instead, the program works perfectly fine, so you don't need to use

```
int time=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

as it may be a bit more complicated (in my opinion) than just replacing `nextLine()` with `next()`. Here is the code:

```
 import java.util.*;
        public class Main{
            public static void main(String args[]){
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                int time = sc.nextInt();
                String input[] = new String[time];
                for(int i = 0;i < time;i++) 
                {
                   input[i] = sc.next();
                }
                for(int i = 0;i < time;i++) 
                {   
                   int len = input[i].length();
                   if(len > 4)
                   {
                      System.out.println(input[i].charAt(0) + Integer.toString(len - 2) + input[i].charAt(len - 1));
                   }
                   else
                      System.out.println(input[i]);
                }
                sc.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying but i am considering the case when my string include space in it.